# Dynamic elements in jQuery $.each

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
  var supportOnInput = 'oninput' in document.createElement('input');

  $("input[maxlength], textarea[maxlength]").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var maxLength = parseInt($this.attr('maxlength'));
    $this.attr('maxlength', null);

    var el = $("<span class=\"character-count label bg-success\">" + maxLength + "</span>");
    el.insertAfter($this);

    $this.bind(supportOnInput ? 'input' : 'keyup', function() {
      var cc = $this.val().length;
      el.text(maxLength - cc);
      if(maxLength < cc) {
        el.addClass("bg-danger");
      } else {
        el.removeClass("bg-danger");
      }
    });
  });
```

The problem is there are dynamically-generated input elements it needs to account for. Changing `bind` to `on` won't necessarily solve it since the problem lies in the `each` iterator. Is there a smart solution for getting that to work?

**UPDATE:**

To elaborate on the problem, I have a comment form that accepts input up to a certain length. The script above performs client-side validation for the length of the field. It works fine normally, but if the field itself was generated dynamically (say, a post added via AJAX that has a comment field that needs this validation), it doesn't work. I presume it's occurring in the `$.each()` iterator function, because that only looks through the currently-existing elements when the page is loaded, and it's not bound the way `.on()` is. So, my question is, what's the smartest way to replace the above code so it DOES work with dynamically generated elements?

Comment: Could you elaborate the actual problem?

Comment: You may use event delegaton then http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on()`:

```
var supportOnInput = 'oninput' in document.createElement('input');

$('body').on( supportOnInput ? 'input' : 'keyup', ".maxlength", function() {
    // do your stuff here
});
```

Note the selector is by class `.maxlength`

Comment: I switched to `.on()` which is going to be necessary for the solution, I'm sure, but that alone doesn't solve it :-(. The problem is the `$.each()` iterator preceding it is selecting elements existing as of document load.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by turning it into a plugin instead.

```
(function($) {


$.fn.lilCharacterCount = function() {
    var supportOnInput = 'oninput' in document.createElement('input');
    var $this = $(this);
    var maxLength = parseInt($this.attr('maxlength'));
    var $counter = $("<span class=\"character-count label bg-success\">" + maxLength + "</span>");
    $counter.insertAfter($this);

    $this.on(supportOnInput ? 'input' : 'keyup', function() {
      var charCount = $this.val().length;

      $counter.text(maxLength - charCount);
      if(maxLength <= charCount) {
        $counter.removeClass("bg-success");
        $counter.addClass("bg-danger");
      } else {
        $counter.removeClass("bg-danger");
        $counter.addClass("bg-success");
      }
    });
  }
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to remove the binding from the .each() and use it as such:

here is an excerpt in dealing with ".on":

**Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().**

I believe this won't be an option for you. Try using ".delegate".

```
 $( "body" ).delegate("input[maxlength], textarea[maxlength]", 
             supportOnInput ? 'input' : 'keyup', function( event ) {
    // do your stuff
 });
```

Comment: .on() can be used to delegate. In fact, .on() effectively replaces .delegate() in the current version of jQuery. Delegating with .on() is done like this: $("body").on("click", ".foo", function() {// your event handler});